# Split Custom Line Item in magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-grid, order-items, order-splitting

I need a functionality to split custom line item in magento 2.3.4 .
For example, suppose Product A has custom addon Child A, then by default magento will show like this Product-A-Child-A in sales order details page. But i want functionality to split this line items into 2 different items like this Product-A & Child-A.

For More clarification currently we have this type of sku in sales order details page .
[image: current situation]

What i want sku for line custom items .
[image]

Comment: Please share screenshot. What you want ?

Comment: added image clarification

Comment: You can't directly split at the order level. You need to add on product as a separate cart item while adding to cart since totals are calculated before place order.

Comment: as i am newbie to magento , did you any reference for the same ?